# How to implement Iterable<E>

Tags: dart

I am trying to port the Java code below to Dart and am puzzled about to do this.

In Java the Iterable interface is where clean with one method and to implement this is a snap.

How is this code best transformed to Dart?

```java
/**
 * Chess squares represented as a bitmap.
 */
public class ChessSquares implements Iterable<ChessSquare> {

private static class ChessSquaresIterator implements Iterator<ChessSquare> {
    long bits;
    int nextBit;

    public ChessSquaresIterator(long bits) {
        this.bits = bits;
        nextBit = Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(bits);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (nextBit < 64);
    }

    @Override
    public ChessSquare next() {
        ChessSquare sq = ChessSquare.values()[nextBit];
        bits = bits & ~sq.bit;
        nextBit = Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(bits);
        return sq;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}


@Override
public Iterator<ChessSquare> iterator() {
    return new ChessSquaresIterator(bits);
}

...
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By using `IterableMixin` you only need to implement the `iterator`-function.

```dart
class ChessSquares with IterableMixin<ChessSquare> {
    @override
    Iterator<ChessSquare> get iterator => new ChessSquaresIterator(bits);
    ...
}
```

Visit http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/03/first-look-at-dart-mixins.html for a short introduction on mixins.

The `Iterator`-interface is straight forward. You only have to implement the function `moveNext` and the getter `current`.

Comment: Fails for me:
```
class ChessSquare{}

class ChessSquares extends Object with IterableMixin<ChessSquare> {
  Iterator<ChessSquare> iterator() => null;
}
```
Gets:
error: Class 'ChessSquares' can't define method 'iterator' and have field 'Iterable.iterator' with the same name. (conflicting_method_and_field at [flutterui] lib/state/sample.dart:330)

Comment: Needs  `Iterator<ChessSquare> get iterator()` to resolve.
This is a better answer than the accepted solution (when fixed and compiles).

Comment: Fixed the code to work with the current version of Dart. Also removed `extends Object` as that's not required anymore either.

Answer (score 2):

Soo I tried this which is kind of not what I want since I do not want to extend a base class.

```dart
/**
 * Chess squares represented as a bitmap.
 */
class ChessSquares extends IterableBase<ChessSquare> {

  Iterator<ChessSquare> get iterator {
    return new ChessSquaresIterator(this);
  }

  ...

}

class ChessSquaresIterator implements Iterator<ChessSquare> {
  int _nextBit;
  int64 _bits;
  ChessSquare _current;
 
  ChessSquaresIterator(ChessSquares squares) {
    _bits = new int64.fromInt(squares._bits); 
  }

  bool moveNext() {
    _nextBit = _bits.numberOfTrailingZeros();
    if (_nextBit < 64) {
      _current = ChessSquare.values()[_nextBit];
      _bits = _bits & ~_current.bit();
    } else {
      _current = null;
    }
    return _nextBit < 64;
  }
 
  E get current => _current;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to extend a base class, mix in the Mixin class.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the mixin class? IterableMixin is defined as `abstract class IterableMixin<E> implements Iterable<E> `, and so it would seem it also a base class, not a mixin/interface.